# Ruby on Rails: Display Number of Search Results Found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, count

I would like to display whatever number of items has been found and returned to the user. In my database, there are 4 items. The search feature works fine. What I now want to display is whatever number of records has been found. If user searches "aI", 2 items gets returned and I want to display the text that 2 items has been found. I tried to do that in view --> layout --> application.html.erb.

Comment: How are you rendering the view after search?

Comment: please paste the controller code and the view where you are printing the number of record

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to count the actual results. **Product** (with a capital p) will always return all objects of that class in the database. Hence 26. Save the result in an ivar (**@products**) and call count on that in your view instead.

**In Controller**

```
@products = Product.fuzzy_search2(params[:search_string])
```

**In View**

```
<% if @products %>
<span> <%= @products.count %> Books Found</span>
<% end %>
```

Comment: you would like to update the result with @result in view

Comment: I have updated the example to reflect your specific implementation.

Comment: what a legend. Thanks a lot but I am getting another problem now after inserting that code in view. If I search, it will work fine but when I click on login button, register button, I will get this error: undefined method `count' for nil:NilClass

Comment: If you are using the view with other controllers that may not pass the @products ivar you would have to check for its existence. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you are storing the search results in an ivar. You need to call `.count` on that ivar or `.size` / `.length` if it's stored in an array. The issue is that when you are calling `Product.count` you are getting the count of all products in your database always, because that's exactly what you are telling it to do.